# A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

After testing out the login button at https://kalvinfromcode.github.io/aftermath/login.html, the console displays:

> A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

I have tried searching similar responses, but they do not work. The login button should have displayed "There is no user record corresponding to this email," indicating that Firebase was successfully reached.

Comment: error fixed: changed form to div

Comment: I changed form tag to div but again I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this issue by doing:
**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist**